# CSS External Font Not Functioning In Div

Tags: html, css, styles

Recently I downloaded a font for my site and renammed it "a.ttf". When I try embeding it into a CSS id for a div however, it doesn't seem functional. Does anyone know the problem here? Thank you very much and have a great day! I forgot to mention also my external CSS page is functioning as I have working classes in other divs. I just inspected element and it now says Failed to decode downloaded font. WHAT DOES THIE MEAN. ARGGHHH! :-)

**CSS Code**

```
@font-face 
{
font-family: a;
src:url("a.ttf");
}

#text
{
color: white;
font-family: a;
font-size: 25px;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: left;
margin-left: 15px;
margin-top: 20px;
}
```

**HTML Div**

```
<div id="text">Test Div</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I think the code you are using is wrong. If you go to [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) and download a font kit this is the recommended way to add custom fonts

```
@font-face{ 
font-family: 'MyWebFont';
src: url('WebFont.eot');
src: url('WebFont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('WebFont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('WebFont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('WebFont.svg#webfont') format('svg');
```

}

You need more that one extension for the font so it works in all browsers.
Also where is your font located??... the path might not be the same as you css file

Comment: It's in the same path as my html file so all I do with this kit is rename MyWebFont with my font's name? thanks

Comment: where is your css file? if all files are in the root folder then yes... you just need to replace...but also you need to get the files for the other extensions.. my recommendation is to go to FontSquirrel and generate a web font

Answer (score 0):

I think you try this one...

**Css**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'a';
  src: url('a.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
#text{
 color: white;
 font-family: a;
 font-size: 25px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: left;
 margin-left: 15px;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You missed the `font-family: 'a';` in `#text`.

Comment: Nope still nothing even with that... I think it somehow isn't detecting the font even though it's in the same directory as this html file. Weird

Comment: Oh I just inspected element and it now says Failed to decode downloaded font

Comment: I think its the problem with the font. Check it out.

Comment: But how would I fix a Failed to decode downloaded font error, super confused thank you by the way.

Comment: download the font again... it might help. Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

1. use single quote in `src:url('a.ttf');`
2. make sure that the (a.ttf) in the same path of css file.

> Internet Explorer has some ttf support starting with version 9, but
>   "only working when [fonts are] set to be installable".

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the `@font-face` rule, please ensure you use the following syntax:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'My Font';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url('../path/to/My-Font.ttf') format('ttf');
}
```

The error you seem to be getting means the file (font file) you download may have been damaged while it was getting downloaded or it may have been damaged on the server itself. I recommend you download the font again from the same website OR download it again from a different site.

When you are going to use a custom font, please ensure you use the following syntax:

```
#text {
    color: white;
    **font-family: 'My Font'**;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Of course, if you copy my code, make sure you take out the asterisk (*).

---

Here is some more information about the `@font-face` rule, here:

> http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

Here:

> https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

And, here:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face